# Can getSymbols still work with oanda?

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to get the data of currencies and metals. As I tried some packages, many person suggest quantmod. So I used `getSymbols` as the following:

```
getSymbols("USD/EUR",src="oanda")
Error in download.file(paste(oanda.URL, from.date, to.date, "exch=", currency.pair[1],  : 
cannot open URL 'http://www.oanda.com/convert/fxhistory?lang=en&date1=09%2F28%2F13&date=02%2F09%2F15&date_fmt=us&exch=USD&expr2=EUR&margin_fixed=0&SUBMIT=Get+Table&format=CSV&redirected=1'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(oanda.URL, from.date, to.date, "exch=", currency.pair[1],  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

as I used:

```
getSymbols("USD/EUR",src="oanda",from="2015-01-01")
```

I get the same message.

So `getSymbols` can still work with Oanda?

And another question is where I can find the list of the symbols that the web-service such as Yahoo, Oanda, Google supported? In fact I don't need the stock symbols, I just need the symbols for the future such as corn, gold and the currency.

Answer (score 4):

Oanda changed their URL structure and file format. I [fixed this over the weekend](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/36). You would need to look on the website of each respective provider in order to find what symbols they support.